# Why does PHP have interfaces?

Tags: php, object-oriented, interfaces, static-typing, duck-typing

I noticed that as of PHP5, interfaces have been added to the language. However, since PHP is so loosely typed, it seems that most of the benefits of using interfaces is lost. Why is this included in the language?

Comment: I think the correct question is, why not?

Comment: because they don't seem to offer any benefit, so why include them?

Comment: you not seeing benefit != there not being benefit: a large part of the [Standard PHP Library](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) makes use of interfaces, so you can see how they are used and useful in there.

Comment: @HorusKol and before they were implemented, they weren't used, so you can see how they were unused and useless just a version prior. You have to also make and support the claim that their use is somehow an improvement to say that they are useful.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs - that's a bit specious... hammers weren't used before they were invented, but they are useful now that they have been.

Comment: @HorusKol Not specious at all. It's easy to demonstrate the value proposition of the hammer. This question is asking for someone to demonstrate the value proposition of PHP interfaces, not just to declare that they are valuable in an argumentative manner.

Comment: PHP can become typed when it comes to object orientation.

Comment: And remember that interfaces aren't only about typing. An interface is a _contract_ stating that an implementing class _must_ include the methods it lays out.  Useful for things like plugin engines.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The main advantage of interfaces in PHP is that classes can implement multiple interfaces.  This allows you to group classes that share some functionality but do not necessarily share a parent class.  Some examples might include caching, output, or accessing properties of the class in a certain way.

In your code, you can check if a class implements a given interface instead of checking the class name.  Then, your code will still work when new classes are added.

PHP provides some predefined interfaces that may come in handy in various situations: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.interfaces.php.

EDIT - Adding an example

If you have an interface named MyInterface and you're working with multiple objects of different classes that may or may not share some functionality, interfaces allow you to do something like this:

```
// Assume $objects is an array of instances of various classes
foreach($objects as $obj) {
 if($obj instanceof MyInterface) {
     $obj->a();
     $obj->b();
     $obj->c();
   }
}
```

Comment: In other words: "you can completely ignore all benefits of dynamic-typed languages"

Comment: @Kamil, I think of it more as being able to take advantage of the benefits of static typing without suffering the drawbacks when you don't want them.

Comment: @Kamil checkout the edit I just made.  It shows a clear example of when using an interface can cut out the need for a complex condition to check if methods a, b, c  etc are available to a given object.

Comment: @pjskeptic, sure but `instanceof` is considered a code smell in static languages and are pretty much useless in dynamic languages. Duck-typing is a nicer approach I think.

Comment: are you serious? instanceof? if-then-if-then-if-then-all-the-time, doesn't it sound familiar? ah, yes, procedural programming.

Comment: Obviously the need for interfaces isn't as strong in dynamic languages.  I was just providing an example of a possible use...

Comment: @Kamil Tomšík Yet another insult at the language of PHP rather than the people who use it incompetently. PHP has all the tools for complete object-oriented programming. Whether or not you use those is up to the programmer. Furthermore, there's nothing wrong with procedural programming in and of itself.

Comment: @Lotus Notes except scattering related code... procedural programming is okay for prototyping, but not for longer run. That's what OOP was designed for. You have to do it properly to get all of its benefits (means no procedural mess anywhere). And please don't flame, you obviously have different opinion.

Comment: @Kamil - how odd, by reading your comment one might come to conclusion that there are no if-s in OOP and that somehow, magically - things get to work. Wow.

Comment: @MichaelJ.V. yes, it's called polymorphism.

Comment: @Michael J.V: Using if's and instanceof is not the OOP way to do things: instead, one should use dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Having interfaces in a loosely typed language is a nonsense. What is the benefit of having interfaces if you have to check the type with instanceof anyway?

Comment: There's a ton of nonsense in PHP.  I was just answering the question.  I think the benefit of an interface is that you can call instanceof once and then call all of the methods that you expect the object to have vs calling method_exists for each method.  Hence the a, b, c method calls in my example.

Comment: @pjskeptic How adding new classes irritate ? just curious and looking for an example.

Answer (score 23):

PHP is loosely typed, but it can be strongly typed about things like method parameters.

Consider the following example:

```
interface Car { function go(); }

class Porsche { function go() {} }

function drive(Car $car) {}

$porsche = new Porsche();

drive($porsche);
```

The above code would output:

> Argument 1 passed to drive() must implement interface Car, instance of Porsche given

Comment: The sad thing about this is, now that you have specified `Car` type you can't pass `null` (error is thrown).  What they were thinking with that one, I don't know.

Comment: Sure, it's too bad. You can have a `null` default value for the parameter, though.

Comment: but if `drive` requires a `Car`, then passing `null` wouldn't be very helpful anyway...

Comment: Never pass null. Use a "Special Case" object (Google for Martin Fowler's explanation).

Comment: @Renesis If you set the default value to null, you can pass null into type hinted methods. (CAR $car = null) would allow you to call this method with null as an argument. This would be a pretty silly practice however. Why on earth would you want to be able to do that?

Comment: @dqhendricks and @all: PHP doesn't have overloadable methods.  Say you have a constructor or a constructor-like method that takes several possible parameters in one call, and for all of them null is a completely sensible value.  If you want to set a value to the 1st and 3rd, but not the second, you might pass `null` to the 2nd.  So, good tip on the `= null`.

Comment: Concrete example:  `function addView($name, Template $template, SecurityMode $securityMode = null, $methodName = null);` You might have a `$methodName` but no `$securityMode`.

Comment: @Renesis: In your example, you imply that you manage the case where the $securityMode would be null in the method addView(). If null is an expected behaviour, you should encapsulate it in a class NullSecurityMode that implements your interface SecurityMode instead.

Comment: @Renesis: wouldn't function addViewByName(...) be better? Or even better yet an addView($view) that takes a view object that could be one of several types, depending on if you have a $methodName but no $securityMode, or any other combination.

Comment: @tylermac `addView($view)` is too verbose, since this is in the context of site setup where there are many of these calls in a row. (In this example, it actually does construct Views inside the method, so this is a convenience method.)  I could see going with `addView` and `addSecureView` where all parameters are always required (except maybe `$methodName`).

Comment: Passing null can be done in any statically typed language. That's because you're moving pointers and not value types, and null is a valid pointer in itself, even though it points to nothing.

Comment: @YamMarcovic There are plenty of statically typed languages that have separate types for nullable references.  It can actually be quite useful since you often know whether some argument is required, in which case it is better to detect the problem at compile time.

Comment: I actually haven't heard of any. Can you refer me to one?

Comment: @YamMarcovic Here's an example: Haskell is a statically typed language (with a stronger type system than PHP and the usual 'static' OOP languages) and it has no nulls. Therefore, you cannot pass null to a function. A whole family of bugs goes away as soon as the compiler statically assures that yes, you are getting a value, and not null. You can use the `Maybe` monad for "optional" values, but it doesn't work like `null` in unsafe languages, and it can never surprise you.

Comment: You have to run the program in order to detect the type mismatch error.

Answer (score 9):

Interfaces allow you to implement the open-closed principle, maintain a loosely coupled code base, and implement many of the best OOP design patterns.

For instance, if one class accepts another class as an argument:

```
class A {

    public function __construct(B $class_b) {
        // use class b
        $class_b->run();
    }
}
```

Your class A and class B now have a tight coupling, and class A cannot use any other class except B and its sub classes. The type hinting makes sure that you have the correct type of argument, but has now cemented the relationship between A and B.

Lets say that you want class A to be able to use all types of classes that have a run() method however. This is basically (but not quite) the COMMAND design pattern. To solve, you would instead type hint using an interface instead of a concrete class. B would then implement that interface, and will be accepted as an argument for class A. This way class A can accept any class that uses that interface as an argument for its constructor.

This type of coding is used in most OOP design patterns, and allows for MUCH easier changes of code at a later time. These are part of the fundamentals of AGILE programming.

```
class A {

    public function __construct(C $interface_c) {
        // use any class that implements interface C
        $interface_c->run();
    }
}

interface C {

    public function run();
}

class B implements C {

    public function run() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Or any subclass of B

Answer (score 7):

@pjskeptic has [a good answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66138/why-does-php-have-interfaces/66150#66150), and @Kamil Tomšík has a good comment on that answer.

The great thing about dynamically typed languages like PHP is that you can try to use methods on objects and it won't scream at you unless the method isn't there.

The issue with dynamically typed languages like PHP is that you can try to use methods on objects and it will scream at you when the method isn't there.

Interfaces add a convenient way of calling methods on an unknown object and being certain that the methods are there (not that they're necessarily correct or going to work). It's not a necessary part of a language, but it makes coding more convenient. It allows strongly typed OOP developers to write strongly typed PHP code, which can then work alongside loosely typed PHP code written by a different PHP developer.

a function like:

```
foo( IBar $bar )
{
  $baz = $bar->baz();
  ...
}
```

is more convenient than:

```
foo( $bar )
{
  if ( method_exists( $bar, 'baz' ) )
  {
    $baz = $bar->baz();
  }
  else
  {
    throw new Exception('OMGWTF NO BAZ IN BAR!');
  }
  ...
}
```

and IMHO simple, readable code is better code.

Comment: what you do instead is just not check for the method and crash and burn when someone calls your function with the wrong data. It's not your problem if someone uses your function wrong.

Comment: no exactly - your example is nightmare for anyone who want to pass any dynamic "duck", like proxy, adapter, decorator etc.

Comment: @Kamil? How so. A proxy would be a wrapper class for a something that doesn't implement the interface to allow it be used with this function.

Comment: @tylermac dynamic proxy using __call() - and if __call is the only method there, it simply can't implement IBar, which means you can't pass it to foo(IBar $bar)

Answer (score 5):

They're completely useless if you're duck-typer, actually when you do duck-typing, it's pretty annoying to work with libraries/framework which use any type-hinting.

This applies also for all sorts of dynamic meta-programming (magic methods).

Answer (score 4):

PHP is **not** loosely or strongly, but [dynamically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_typing#Dynamic_typing).

About interfaces, the first thing you should ask yourself is: what are most of the benefits of interfaces?

In OOP, interfaces are not just about types, but about behaviour as well.

Since PHP also has a [type hint feature](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), you can use interfaces just as you would in a pure oo language, such as Java.

```
interface File
{
    public function getLines();
}

CSVFile implements File
{
    public function getLines()
    {}
}

XMLFile implements File 
{
    public function getLines()
    {}
}

JSONFile implements File 
{
    public function getLines()
    {}
}

class FileReader
{
    public function read(File $file)
    {
        foreach($file->getLines() as $line)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

With PHP interface implementation, you cal also create mocks for abstract classes using [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de) - and this is a hell of a feature:

```
public function testSomething()
{
    $mock = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('File');

    $mock->expects($this->once())
         ->method('getLines')
         ->will($this->returnValue(array()));

    // do your assertions
}
```

So, basically, you can have a [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) compatible application in PHP by using the language features, one of them being interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are useful for dependency injection much more so than concrete. As a barebones example :

```
interface Istore { 
  public function save(); 
}

class Article_DB implements Istore 
{ 
  public function save($data) 
  {
    // do save to format needed.
  } 
}

class Article
{
   private $content;

   public function content($content)
   {
     $this->content = $content;
   }

   public function save(Istore $store)
   {
     $store->save($this->content);
   }
}

$article = new Article();
$article->content('Some content');

$store = new Article_DB();
$article->save($store);
```

Now say if your needs change and you want to save to a pdf. You could create a a new class for that purpose instead of polluting the Article class.

```
class Article_PDF implements Istore 
{ 
  public function save($data) 
  {
    // do save to format needed.
  } 
}


$article = new Article();
$article->content('Some content');

$store = new Article_PDF();
$article->save($store);
```

The Article class now has a contract that classes it uses to save must implement the Istore interface. It does not care where it saves or how it saves.

Answer (score -1):

You can provide "Fake" real objects that implement the interface. You could then unit test a part of your code without requiring real servers, file systems, sockets, databases etc.

Answer (score -3):

Lots of people will probably hate me for answering this way but the solution to your typing problems can be easily fixed with PHP. *Yes* PHP is loosely typed so types are assumed by default, which *can* cause some problems, especially in comparison operations which is most peoples problem with it. That being said, PHP can be just as strict as any strongly typed language if you cast what you are using into the type you need it to be, and then use bitwise comparison operators. Here is the easiest example I can think of of what I am saying:

$myVar = (int) 0;
$myOtherVar = '0';

comparing ($myVar == $myVar) would equal (bool) true

but comparing ($myVar === $myVar) would equal (bool) false just like any "typed" comparison

I really just wish developers would stop arguing about these things, if you have a problem with the way PHP works either go program in java and live and let live, or use it in the way that it will do what you want it to... What good does bitching about it do for you anyway? Give you an excuse to screw around all day? Make you look better than someone else? Well it's great that you feel so highly about yourself that you're willing to make someone else look bad but in reality it's your preference and forcing your beliefs on anyone really just makes them code in a way they are not comfortable with causing three things:

1) They will code your way but "messy" by your standards (think, have you ever seen a java programmer create their first PHP program or vice versa? It will be the same way changing their methodology or maybe even worse.)

2) You will find something else to whine about

3) It will probably take longer for them to produce. And maybe it will make you look better in the short term, but the team as a whole will look worse for it (remember you may code slower than someone else and that's not necessarily bad as long as the team meets deliverables in a reasonable timeframe, but forcing your habits on someone who has typically performed a little faster may end up making your whole team slow down thus, look worse in a very demanding workflow)

I personally prefer writing procedural PHP code although I can, and have, written full programs using OOP in a few different languages. That being said, I have seen good OOP code and bad OOP code, and good procedural code and bad procedural code for that matter... It really has nothing to do with the practice, but with the *habits* that you use and even then, a lot of things are my interpreted feelings... that does not mean I am going to talk bad about those developers or say brag with "my way is best" B.S., it's just right for me, and the company I work for is pretty happy with my work and I'm proud of that. There are reasons a standard should be established but what you include in the standard you choose is VERY important... Thanks for letting me get that off my chest. Have a great day.

Answer (score -4):

1. Interfaces is a part of OOP paradigm. So it's very useful in many cases when you trying to make object oriented parts or your system.
2. So. Why not? ;-)

Examples:
You need to cache your data. How? There is a lot of different engines for caching, which one is the best? Who cares if you have abstract layer which have some ICacheDriver interface with a set of methods like key, get, put, clear, etc. Just implement to it what you need in current project and change it when you need another.
Or simple usage of toString. You have a set of different showable objects. You just implement Stringable interface (which describes toString method [there is no really interfaces like that in PHP, but for example]) and just interating over all your object with (string)$obj. There is all you need to do instead of switch (true) { case $obj isntanceof A1: "do 1"; break; ... }

Simple. So there is no question "Why?". There is "how to use that better?". ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score -5):

My guess.

PHP is used by **many entry level programmers**, entry level programmers are **taught java** in college.

After their Programming 101 course they start nagging Zend they want java features because that's the way they have been taught to think, an thinking on your own terms (or understanding duck typing) it's hard, when you're only 20.

Zend is pragmatic, it's **easier to add the feature** other than to pretend they where right all along.
This also buys in **more users** instead of making them leave, so it must be good.

Another instance of this process? People fresh out of .NET and Java courses also want **Frameworks of Foundation Classes**, they nag about it until Zend sprouts out the **Zend Framework**. This buys in even more users. And on and on...

(the only language feature the PHP team is known to have **struggled against**, over the years, is `goto`)

Comment: In my vision, `PHP12` will probably have all the syntax features of the world (I hope it doesn't get an abstraction layer runtime, tough, as that's what killed perl) with a wink to functional and datatype paradigms, and still no `goto`.

Comment: "it's hard, when you're only 20" How could age possibly have anything to do with understanding any of those concepts?

Comment: @Evicatos high schoolers sort-of program, but they usually have bad teachers, poor naming conventions, and produce unmaintainable blobs. They learn to program *right* while starting college, it takes a couple of years to get it going. Then they start to diverge from the hard-typed, industry-blessed, accademically-acclaimed, languages they've been taught in those first years, and turn to, more pragmatic, duck-typed, ones. **I believe this is a bushido many programmers share.** Then again, this might not reflect your experience, you might be a self-taught savant. If so, show us the way.